# How can I parse the json string in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, json

This is the dictionary that I have given for the `json.dumps` in my `views.py`

```
{1: {'status': u'up', 'count': 8}, 2: {'status': u'down', 'count': 12}}
```

I have to use this in my javascript. I have tried the following way but not working for me.

```
var mydata = json.loads({{indexdata}});
```

can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: And what template language is this? Is this Flask, Django, something else?

Comment: And Javascript doesn't have a `json` module; that's Python code only.

Comment: `var mydata = {{indexdata}};` ?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, that is Django template language and I have no idea what to write in Javascript, that is the reason why I need help

Comment: JSON is essentially a JavaScript Object, why would you need to 'parse' it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var mydata = {{indexdata}};
```

Answer (score 0):

java script interprets things like you've posted as an object. you don't need any conversion.

```
var myObj = {a : { b : 5 }}
```

is a valid js object